# Why is “coma” countable in “go into a coma”?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

I came across a phrase “go into a coma” and wonder why “coma” is countable here. Is there any rule which determines a noun followed by “go into” is countable or uncountable?

Here are some other examples with “go into”:

- Go into bankruptcy
- Go into debt
- Go into work

And ones with “get into” and “give”, where I cannot find an obvious rule either.

- Get into trouble
- Get into a habit
- Get into an argument
- Get into a panic
- Get into a temper
- Get into debt
- Give a cough
- Give a cry
- Give a ride
- Give a shock
- Give trouble
- Give love
- Give a punch
- Give a cold

Comment: I don't think there is a rule. I think it is one of the many unpredictable matters in the English lexicon.

Answer (score 2):

You've gone to the trouble of looking up all the other words in your examples, and any decent dictionary should also tell you if a noun is countable or not, as well as how to use it.

Taking a couple of your examples:

*Bankruptcy* is a *legal process*. You follow a process, it has various steps, so it is not a countable thing. You enter into *the* process of bankruptcy.

*Debt* is a little more complex, because obviously, you can have many debts, so debts are countable. However, "debt" is also a collective term for all the money you may owe - you can have "some debt", a "little debt" or "a lot of debt"; you are also *in debt* to the person who loaned it to you.

A coma, however, is the *name* for a *state* that a person can be in. You can be in a coma, come out of it, and then slip into another one. You can't be in more than one coma at once (unlike debt!) and if you come out of that state and slip into it again those two events are marked separately.

Really, the "rule" which determines whether *any* noun is countable or uncountable, whether it is idiomatic to say you "go into" it or not, is that if you can count it, it is countable!

I do appreciate that there are some odd idiomatic examples when it comes to medical conditions (and perhaps other things too) - for example, most people say they have "*a* cold" but say they have "*the* flu" (or simply just "flu"!). There are definitely things to consider as I outlined above, but you can't go far wrong if you follow the usage examples in your dictionary.

Comment: By the logic you gave for *a coma*, *remission* should also be countable. Except that it isn't. So, there must be more to it than what you've said.

Comment: @JasonBassford I don't see how it is? Dictionary definition of *remission* is "a temporary *diminution* of the severity of disease or pain". So it is the name for a marked period of a condition that a person already has, or a phase in the life of that condition, not really a state that the person is in. The most common example is *cancer*. A person *has* cancer, they are not "in" cancer. But cancer can be in remission.

Comment: People are said to be *in remission* (they never *have* remission). There is no article used. And this remission can last years. People can also go in and out of remission multiple times. And while it's sometimes used to talk about cancer, that is often just assumed. Everything you said about comas can apply equally to remission. Yet, one takes an article and the other doesn't.

Comment: @JasonBassford Does "in hospital" mean the same as "in *a* hospital"? No. One means you are in the building and the other is the idiomatic way to say you have been *admitted*. Likewise, "in remission" is the idiomatic way to say that somebody's cancer is in remission phase. If a person came out of remission and then went back in they would be described as "back in remission" or "in another period of remission". This is nothing like "coma"... a person "is in a coma". They don't *have* a coma, nor are they "in a period of coma". However, they are *in a comatose state*

Comment: @JasonBassford Not in the UK hospital where I work. I am in a hospital every day, for work. There are also thousands of visitors here. But if I said "my dad is in hospital" *everybody* would take that to mean he had been admitted as a patient, not that he just happened to be in *a* hospital for some other reason.